# Hand-create images in javascript and draw with respect to the alpha channel?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently trying to create a page with dynamically generated images, which are not shapes, drawn into a canvas to create an animation.

The first thing I tried was the following:

```
//create plenty of those:
var imageArray = ctx.createImageData(0,0,16,8);
//fill them with RGBA values...
//then draw them
ctx.putImageData(imageArray,x,y);
```

The problem is that the images are overlapping and that `putImageData` simply... puts the data in the context, with no respect to the alpha channel as specified in the w3c:

> pixels in the canvas are replaced wholesale, with no composition, alpha blending, no shadows, etc.

So I thought, well how can I use `Image`s and not `ImageData`s?

I tried to find a way to actually put the `ImageData` object back into an image but it appears it can only be put in a canvas context. So, as a last resort, I tried to use the `toDataURL()` method of a 16x8 canvas(the size of my images) and to stick the result as `src` of my ~600 images.

The result was beautiful, but was eating up 100% of my CPU...(which it did not with `putImageData`, ~5% cpu) My guess is that for some unknown reason the  image is re-loaded from the `image/png` data URI each time it is drawn... but that would be plain weird... no? It also seems to take a lot more RAM than my previous technique.

So, as a result, I have no idea how to achieve my goal.

How can I dynamically create alpha-channelled images in javascript and then draw them at an appreciable speed on a canvas?

Is the only real alternative using a Java applet?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing, what you really want to accomplish:

Did you have a look at the `drawImage`-method of the rendering-context?
Basically, it does the composition (as specified by the `globalCompositeOperation`-property) for you -- and it allows you to pass in a canvas element as the source.

So could probably do something along the lines of:

```
var offScreenContext = document.getCSSCanvasContext( "2d", "synthImage", width, height);
var pixelBuffer = offScreenContext.createImageData( tileWidth, tileHeight );
// do your image synthesis and put the updated buffer back into the context:
offScreenContext.putImageData( pixelBuffer, 0, 0, tileOriginX, tileOriginY, tileWidth, tileHeight );
// assuming 'ctx' is the context of the canvas that actually gets drawn on screen
ctx.drawImage(
  offScreenContext.canvas,                          // => the synthesized image
  tileOriginX, tileOriginY, tileWidth, tileHeight,  // => frame of offScreenContext that get's drawn
  originX, originY, tileWidth, tileHeight           // => frame of ctx to draw in
);
```

Assuming that you have an animation you want to loop over, this has the added benefit of only having to generate the frames once into some kind of sprite-map so that in subsequent iterations you'll only ever need to call `ctx.drawImage()` -- at the expense of an **increased memory footprint** of course...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use SVG?

If you have to use canvas, maybe you could implement drawing an image on a canvas yourself?

```
var red = oldred*(1-alpha)+imagered*alpha
```

...and so on...

Comment: SVG to create my images? or to apply the alpha mask? I'm not really sure how to do that. As for implementing the draw functions myself, afaik the code behind this is native code, so I don't think I can really do this. Or manipulating the whole canvas' pixel array pixel-wise? it's gonna be quite slow...

Comment: Manux: Do you think it's slow? At least V8 (used in Google Chrome) afaik compiles Javascript to native code before executing it.

Comment: I'm using chrome; I've just tried this and it's slow, but it's faster than using the URI. I guess I'll have to hack something like this.

Answer (score 0):

getCSSCanvasContext seems to be WebKit only, but you could also create an offscreen canvas like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.setAttribute('width',300);//use whatever you like for width and height
canvas.setAttribute('height',200);
```

Which you can then draw to and draw onto another canvas with the drawImage method.